# Why do I only get results from my first txt?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, readline, txt

I am trying to read & use all lines from txt files. With a method I iterate through them asinc, and I try to get the data. My problem is, the output looks like it only contains the data from the first txt file. I just cant find where the problem is. I would appreciate any help.

Here's my code:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:/DPS-EDPWB05/forlogsearch", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

//data I need from the txts
            List<string> num = new List<string>();
            List<string> date = new List<string>();
            List<string> time = new List<string>();
            List<string> sip = new List<string>();
            List<string> csmethod = new List<string>();
            List<string> csuristem = new List<string>();
            List<string> csuriquery = new List<string>();
            List<string> sport = new List<string>();
            List<string> csusername = new List<string>();
            List<string> cip = new List<string>();
            List<string> csuseragent = new List<string>();
            List<string> csreferer = new List<string>();
            List<string> scstatus = new List<string>();
            List<string> scsubstatus = new List<string>();
            List<string> cswin32status = new List<string>();
            List<string> timetaken = new List<string>();

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int filesCount = 0;
        string v = "";

        //Taking the data from the Log, getting a list of string[] 
        //items with the lines from the txts

        List<string[]> lines = new List<string[]>();

        while (i < files.Length)
        {
            lines.Add(ReadAllLinesAsync(files[i]).Result);
            i++;
        }

        //Trying to get the data from the string[]s
        do
        {
            string line;
            int f = 0;
            string[] linesOfTxt = lines[filesCount];

            do
                {
                line = linesOfTxt[f];

                string[] splittedLine = { };

                    splittedLine = line.Split(' ', 15, StringSplitOptions.None);
                        
                    y = splittedLine.Count();

                    if (y == 15)
                    {
                        num.Add(x.ToString());
                        date.Add(splittedLine[0]);
                        time.Add(splittedLine[1]);
                        sip.Add(splittedLine[2]);
                        csmethod.Add(splittedLine[3]);
                        csuristem.Add(splittedLine[4]);
                        csuriquery.Add(splittedLine[5]);
                        sport.Add(splittedLine[6]);
                        csusername.Add(splittedLine[7]);
                        cip.Add(splittedLine[8]);
                        csuseragent.Add(splittedLine[9]);
                        csreferer.Add(splittedLine[10]);
                        scstatus.Add(splittedLine[11]);
                        scsubstatus.Add(splittedLine[12]);
                        cswin32status.Add(splittedLine[13]);
                        timetaken.Add(splittedLine[14]);

                        x++;
                    }
                
                f++;

                } while (f < linesOfTxt.Length);
            filesCount++;
        }
        while (filesCount < files.Count());
```

After all this I group these and stuff but that happens AFTER the lists of data i need are filled - so the problem must be here somewhere. Also, my asinc reader (I found here on stackoverflow):

```
public static Task<string[]> ReadAllLinesAsync(string path)
        {
            return ReadAllLinesAsync(path, Encoding.UTF8);
        }

        public static async Task<string[]> ReadAllLinesAsync(string path, Encoding encoding)
        {
            var lines = new List<string>();

            // Open the FileStream with the same FileMode, FileAccess
            // and FileShare as a call to File.OpenText would've done.
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, DefaultBufferSize, DefaultOptions))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
                {
                    lines.Add(line);
                }
            }

            return lines.ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: Why do you need `async` here at all? Either way, you aren't awaiting for the async task to finish before reading the `.Result`...

Comment: (Additionally, your data model seems weird – why have a dozen of string arrays instead of a single array of structs/classes containing all of those fields?)

Comment: *your data model seems weird* - the "use N arrays where the data within is assciated by position" is indicative of a procedural programmer coming to OO, IMHO

Comment: Thank you for your comments. 
First, i tried async since my other method (which worked fine by the way) was waaaaaaay tooo slow. This approach solved the slow-reading issue, but now I need to figure out this other problem.
And second, about the data model and stuff: I am new to C# and I am trying to get some experience with it - thought this project would be a nice opportunity to do so. Now I have an issue I just cannot solve and have my brain tangled on this also so I cannot leave it... :)

Comment: @AKX ReadAllLinesAsync does await, I assumed that is enough.

Comment: This will be easier to read and understand if you use `foreach` loops instead of `for` loops with indexes. The `for` loop just adds a an extra variable, and when you have a few of them it's more work for the brain. `foreach(string file in files)`, `foreach(string line in lines)`, etc.

Comment: Thank you guys, I think my code and my question shows that I am a rookie in this. I'll update my code with your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with the example code, thou I'm unsure what is responsible for the actual issue.

1. Instead of writing your own ReadAllLinesAsync, just use [File.ReadAllLinesAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllinesasync?view=net-6.0#system-io-file-readalllinesasync(system-string-system-text-encoding-system-threading-cancellationtoken))
2. You should in general avoid `.Result` since this is a blocking operation, and this has the potential to cause deadlocks. In this case you should just call the synchronous version, `File.ReadAllLines`, instead.
3. When possible, use [foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements) or for loops. They make it much easier to see if your code is correct, and avoids spreading the loop logic over multiple lines.
4. As far as I can see, you are processing each line identically, so you should be able to just merge all lines from all files by using `List<string> lines` and [AddRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=net-6.0)
5. Instead of keeping 15 different lists of properties, a more common approach would be to store one list of objects of a class with 15 different properties.
6. Whenever you need to store data, you should seriously consider using an existing serialization format, like json, xml, csv, protobuf etc. This lets you use existing, well tested, libraries for writing and reading data and converting it to your own types.